# NullPointerException while using constructor in controller class. JavaFX

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, singleton, javafx-2

This is my first post here, so I hope this question isn't a duplicate. I'm a hobbyist who is trying to use JavaFX to create an application which can manage a debating tournament.

I want to create a Singleton object in TournamentCreation, which TournamentEditor can also access and manipulate.

It seems that when my Singleton `GlobalInstance` object is created (which holds a tournament inside it that can be accessed and edited from elsewhere), a `NullPointerException` is thrown. Using debugging I've managed to figure out that it is occurring when `GlobalInstance` calls the default `Tournament` constructor.

Code time. Here is the `TournamentCreationController` where the error begins with the line `GlobalInstance.getInstance().currentTournament().setRounds(roundsIn);`

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import BusinessLogic.GlobalInstance;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class TournamentCreationController implements Initializable , ControlledScreen {

ScreensController myController;

@FXML
TextField nameChooser;

@FXML
ChoiceBox roundNumberChooser;

@FXML
ChoiceBox breakNumberChooser;

@FXML
ChoiceBox noviceBreakNumberChooser;

@FXML
ChoiceBox eslBreakNumberChooser;

@FXML
ChoiceBox proAmBreakNumberChooser;


/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
{
    roundNumberChooser.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));
    roundNumberChooser.getSelectionModel().select(4);

    breakNumberChooser.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(4,8,16,32,64));
    breakNumberChooser.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

    noviceBreakNumberChooser.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(0,4,8,16,32,64));
    noviceBreakNumberChooser.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

    eslBreakNumberChooser.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(0,4,8,16,32,64));
    eslBreakNumberChooser.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

    proAmBreakNumberChooser.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(0,4,8,16,32,64));
    proAmBreakNumberChooser.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();

}

public void setScreenParent(ScreensController screenParent)
{
    myController = screenParent;
}

@FXML
private void goToEditor(ActionEvent event)
{
    String nameIn = nameChooser.getText();
    int roundsIn = (int)roundNumberChooser.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    int openBreakTeamsIn = (int)breakNumberChooser.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    int eslBreakTeamsIn = (int)eslBreakNumberChooser.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    int noviceBreakTeamsIn = (int)noviceBreakNumberChooser.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    int proAmBreakTeamsIn = (int)proAmBreakNumberChooser.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();


    GlobalInstance.getInstance().currentTournament().setRounds(roundsIn);
    GlobalInstance.getInstance().currentTournament().setOpenBreakTeams(openBreakTeamsIn);
    GlobalInstance.getInstance().currentTournament().setESLBreakTeams(eslBreakTeamsIn);
    GlobalInstance.getInstance().currentTournament().setNoviceBreakTeams(noviceBreakTeamsIn);
    GlobalInstance.getInstance().currentTournament().setProAmBreakTeams(proAmBreakTeamsIn);

    myController.setScreen(ScreensFramework.screen4ID);
}

}
```

And here is the Singleton class:

```
public class GlobalInstance
{
private final static GlobalInstance instance = new GlobalInstance();
private Tournament tournament = new Tournament();

public static GlobalInstance getInstance()
{
    return instance;
}

public Tournament currentTournament()
{
    return tournament;
}

}
```

And finally here is the `Tournament` class (ignore most of it, the exact error occurs at `name.set("name")` in the default constructor):

```
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Tournament
{
private StringProperty name;
private IntegerProperty rounds;
private BooleanProperty eslBreak;
private BooleanProperty noviceBreak;
private BooleanProperty proAmBreak;
private IntegerProperty openBreakTeams;
private IntegerProperty eslBreakTeams;
private IntegerProperty noviceBreakTeams;
private IntegerProperty proAmBreakTeams;

public Tournament()
{
name.set("name");
rounds.set(0);
eslBreak.set(false);
noviceBreak.set(false);
proAmBreak.set(false);
openBreakTeams.set(4);
eslBreakTeams.set(0);
noviceBreakTeams.set(0);
proAmBreakTeams.set(0);
}

public Tournament(String nameIn, int roundsIn, int openBreakTeamsIn, int eslBreakTeamsIn, int noviceBreakTeamsIn, int proAmBreakTeamsIn)
{
name.set(nameIn);
rounds.set(roundsIn);
openBreakTeams.set(openBreakTeamsIn);

if(eslBreakTeamsIn==0)
{
    eslBreak.set(false);
    eslBreakTeams.set(0);
}
else
{
    eslBreak.set(true);
    eslBreakTeams.set(eslBreakTeamsIn);
}

if(noviceBreakTeamsIn==0)
{
    noviceBreak.set(false);
    noviceBreakTeams.set(0);
}
else
{
    noviceBreak.set(true);
    noviceBreakTeams.set(noviceBreakTeamsIn);
}

if(proAmBreakTeamsIn==0)
{
    proAmBreak.set(false);
    proAmBreakTeams.set(0);
}
else
{
    proAmBreak.set(true);
    proAmBreakTeams.set(noviceBreakTeamsIn);
}
}

public String getName()
{
    return name.get();
}

public void setName(String nameIn)
{
    name.set(nameIn);
}

public int getRounds()
{
    return rounds.get();
}

public void setRounds(int roundsIn)
{
    rounds.set(roundsIn);
}

public int getOpenBreakTeams()
{
    return openBreakTeams.get();
}

public void setOpenBreakTeams(int openBreakTeamsIn)
{
    openBreakTeams.set(openBreakTeamsIn);
}

public boolean getESLBreak()
{
    return eslBreak.get();
}

public int getESLBreakNumber()
{
    return eslBreakTeams.get();
}

public void setESLBreakTeams(int eslBreakTeamsIn)
{
    if (eslBreakTeamsIn==0)
    {
        eslBreak.set(false);
        eslBreakTeams.set(0);
    }
    else
    {
        eslBreak.set(true);
        eslBreakTeams.set(eslBreakTeamsIn);
    }
}

public boolean getNoviceBreak()
{
    return noviceBreak.get();
}

public int getNoviceBreakNumber()
{
    return noviceBreakTeams.get();
}

public void setNoviceBreakTeams(int noviceBreakTeamsIn)
{
    if (noviceBreakTeamsIn==0)
    {
        noviceBreak.set(false);
        noviceBreakTeams.set(0);
    }
    else
    {
        noviceBreak.set(true);
        noviceBreakTeams.set(noviceBreakTeamsIn);
    }
}

public boolean getProAmBreak()
{
    return proAmBreak.get();
}

public int getProAmBreakNumber()
{
    return proAmBreakTeams.get();
}

public void setProAmBreakTeams(int proAmBreakTeamsIn)
{
    if (proAmBreakTeamsIn==0)
    {
        proAmBreak.set(false);
        proAmBreakTeams.set(0);
    }
    else
    {
        proAmBreak.set(true);
        proAmBreakTeams.set(proAmBreakTeamsIn);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is a ridiculously long and wordy wandering post. Please narrow it all down to target your specific question directly. Provide as much context as necessary but no more.  See [How to Ask A Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [On Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You said people always ask you for more information, but this is your first question here? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I mean when I have seen other questions, but certainly, as soon as I'm able I'll work on tightening this post up.

Comment: Well, answerers want additional info about the problem, not about the verbose description unrelated to problem itself. For example. which code exists at line 84 of TournamentCreationController.java?

Comment: Hi Uluk Biy, sorry I'm not at my computer right now and can't see line numbers. Could you give a small quote of the code you're asking about and I'll explain what I intend with it? I'm going to assume you're asking about the final "myController.setScreen..." code. That is part of my method of changing screens which I got from a tutorial. It works perfectly well, but I think including all of the code and a full explanation for it might be a bit off-topic, but the approach is outlined here: https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1

Comment: @MatthewOldham, it is bit long to add as a comment, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While programming, the error messages are the best helpers for resolving issues. In Java, the root cause of exception can tell the actual problem. So if we look at your use case,

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at TabIt.TournamentCreationController.goToEditor(TournamentCreationController.java:84)
```

tells us, the error occurred in `goToEditor()` method at line 84 of `TournamentCreationController` class. Then if we continue to read the rest of exception tracktrace message, we see the actual root error (cause) of it,

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at BusinessLogic.Tournament.<init>(Tournament.java:24)
```

Here it is saying that the type of error is `NullPointerException` and is at line 24 of `Tournament` class.

These hints are enough to determine the problem.

**UPDATE**

Based on your updated question, the problem is that `name` variable is not initialized yet. Trying to use uninitialized object throws null pointer exception. the Tournament's constructor should be:

```
public Tournament()
{
    name = new SimpleStringProperty("name");
    rounds = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    eslBreak = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    // etc.
}

public Tournament(String nameIn, int roundsIn, int openBreakTeamsIn, int eslBreakTeamsIn, int noviceBreakTeamsIn, int proAmBreakTeamsIn)
{
    name = new SimpleStringProperty(nameIn);
    rounds = new SimpleIntegerProperty(roundsIn);
    eslBreak = new SimpleBooleanProperty(openBreakTeamsIn);
     // etc.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, will go and attempt to hunt the error down!

Comment: Have edited with extra info after tracking this error.

Comment: Thanks very much! All working now. Shall edit as Solved.

Comment: @MatthewOldham no, no need. The question has an accepted answer, so this implies that the problem is solved.